# How to extract hashtags with gsub

Tags: r, regex, string

I would like to extract only hashtags from tweets with gsub .
For example:

```
sentence = tweet_text$text
```

And the result is  `"The #Sun #Halo is out in full force today People need to look up once in awhile to see", \n "inspired #YouthStrikeClimate #FridayForFuture #FridaysFuture #ClimateChange", \n "Multiple warnings in effect for snow and wind with the latest #storm  Metro"`

What I am trying to get is only `#Sun, #halo from the first one. \n #YouthStrikeClimate, #Friday~~ from the second one. #storm From the last one.`

I tried to do this with:

```
sentence = gsub("^(?!#)","",sentence,perl = TRUE) or 
sentence1 = gsub("[^#\\w+]","",sentence,perl = TRUE)
```

whatever. I already deleted useless words like Numbers or http:// so on

How can I extract them with using `gsub`?

Comment: Gsub removes text matched with regex, you can't extract multiple occurrences with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `base R`, we can use `regmatches/gregexpr`

```
regmatches(x, gregexpr("#\\S+", x))
#[[1]]
#[1] "#Sun"  "#Halo"

#[[2]]
#[1] "#YouthStrikeClimate" "#FridayForFuture"    "#FridaysFuture"      "#ClimateChange"     

#[[3]]
#[1] "#storm"
```

About using the `gsub`, either

```
trimws(gsub("(?<!#)\\b\\S+\\s*", "", x, perl = TRUE))
```

or

```
trimws(gsub("(^| )[A-Za-z]+\\b", "", x))
```

would keep the words that start with `#` and separate each word with a space

#### data

```
x <- c("The #Sun #Halo is out in full force today People need to look up once in", 
"inspired #YouthStrikeClimate #FridayForFuture #FridaysFuture #ClimateChange", 
 "Multiple warnings in effect for snow and wind with the latest #storm       Metro"
 )
```

Comment: I'm trying to do it with gsub. I'm studying gsub part. If I can, I want to use only gsub. Do you happen to know the way?

Comment: @Oasis Would `trimws(gsub("(^| )[A-Za-z]+\\b", "", x))` this helps

Answer (score 2):

We could use `str_extract_all` from `stringr` and extract all the words followed by a hash. (`#`).

```
stringr::str_extract_all(x, '#\\w+')

#[[1]]
#[1] "#Sun"  "#Halo"

#[[2]]
#[1] "#YouthStrikeClimate" "#FridayForFuture" "#FridaysFuture"  "#ClimateChange"

#[[3]]
#[1] "#storm"
```

---

A base R approach with minimal regex. We split the string on whitespace and select only those words which `startsWith` `#`.

```
sapply(strsplit(x, "\\s+"), function(p) p[startsWith(p, "#")])
```

**data**

```
x <- c("The #Sun #Halo is out in full force today People need to look up once in", 
  "inspired #YouthStrikeClimate #FridayForFuture #FridaysFuture #ClimateChange", 
  "Multiple warnings in effect for snow and wind with the latest #storm  Metro")
```

Comment: I'm trying to do it with gsub. I'm studying gsub part. If I can, I want to use only gsub. Do you happen to know the way?